# Missing gstreamer and farsight dependencies in pidgin

Tags: c, linux, debian, configure, pidgin

I am trying to compile [pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) and getting the following error on runing the configure script(see below).
This is the newest unstable version of Debian with the 2.6.38-2-686 kernel.
It's not clear for me what dependency I am missing.
Any help appreciated.

```
    checking for GSTREAMER... yes
    checking for gst_registry_fork_set_enabled in -lgstreamer-0.10... yes
    checking for GSTINTERFACES... no
    checking for FARSIGHT... yes
    configure: error: 
    Dependencies for voice/video were not met.
    Install the necessary gstreamer and farsight packages first.
    Or use --disable-vv if you do not need voice/video support.
```

dpkg --get-selectons

```
maciej@wladyslawa:~/workbench/pidgin-2.7.11$ dpkg --get-selections  | egrep -i -e gstream -e farsight
gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10               install
gstreamer0.10-alsa              install
gstreamer0.10-buzztard              install
gstreamer0.10-buzztard-doc          install
gstreamer0.10-doc               install
gstreamer0.10-esd               install
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg                install
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg-dbg            install
gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3           install
gstreamer0.10-gconf             install
gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs              install
gstreamer0.10-gnonlin               install
gstreamer0.10-gnonlin-dbg           install
gstreamer0.10-gnonlin-doc           install
gstreamer0.10-nice              install
gstreamer0.10-packagekit            install
gstreamer0.10-pitfdll               install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad           install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-dbg           install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-doc           install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-base          install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps         install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-dbg          install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-doc          install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-cutter            install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good          install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good-dbg          install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good-doc          install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly          install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-dbg          install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-doc          install
gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio            install
gstreamer0.10-sdl               install
gstreamer0.10-tools             install
gstreamer0.10-x                 install
libgstfarsight0.10-0                install
libgstfarsight0.10-dbg              install
libgstfarsight0.10-dev              install
libgstfarsight0.10-doc              install
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0         install
libgstreamer0.10-0              install
libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg              install
libgstreamer0.10-dev                install
libtelepathy-farsight-dev           install
libtelepathy-farsight0              install
libtelepathy-qt4-farsight0          install
```

Comment: Do you really need voice & video support? If not, why just not add the given option (`--disable-vv`) to your compilation command?

Comment: voted to move this to superuser.com

Comment: Thanks James C, I believe that if any of SE can give me an answer stackoverflow will be the first one, as you have to look at dependencies from programmer's perspective, no end-user's perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in the configure.ac file of pidgin to see exactly what it is looking for to determine if these dependencies are present.  It's using pkg-config to check for dependencies, so it's pretty easy to determine which file it is looking for and then which packages provide those files.  The packages you'll need to install (from debian unstable) are:

```
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
libgstfarsight0.10-dev
```

To figure this out I did the following:

1. Open configure.ac and search for GSTINTERFACES / FARSIGHT (from error message)
2. I noticed the calls to PKG_CHECK_MODULES, which accepts a parameter that corresponds to the name of a file in /usr/lib/pkgconfig if the package is installed.  For gstreamer-interfaces it was gstreamer-interfaces-0.10 and for farsight it was farsight2-0.10.
3. I went to http://packages.debian.org and searched for packages which contain files named like these files.  That turned up these two packages.

Comment: Thank you. The libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev is the library I was missing. Learning every day.

Comment: ahh yeah - just noticed that I overlooked your output which shows that farsight was found.  Glad I could help.